# IF CON CONDICION EN SQL 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, tsql, transact-sql

Tengo esta Query en sql 2014, es valido?  Ya que cuando hago ejecuto esa condicion, cuando la Cantidad Restante sea = 0 me haga la instruccion que le indico abajo que es la de insertar. Pero no lo hace!! Tengo algo mal en el codigo? Si alguien podria decirme o explicarme porque no entra en la condicion.

Saludos!! Y muchas gracias. Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT COD_REG FROM TBL_FS_Lamina_Surtida WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE Cod_Reg = CAST(ltrim(rtrim(@Cod_reg)) as uniqueidentifier) AND EstatusSecuencia != 4 AND NumSolicitud = @NUMSOLICITUD_ACTUAL)
        BEGIN
            SELECT TOP 1  @SALDO_PENDIENTE13 =  CantidadRestante --, @CantidadReSolicitada = ISNULL(CantidadReSolicitada,0)
            FROM TBL_FS_Lamina_Surtida WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE Cod_Reg = CAST(ltrim(rtrim(@Cod_reg)) as uniqueidentifier) 
            --AND EstatusSecuencia != 4
             --AND NumSolicitud = @NUMSOLICITUD_ACTUAL
             and CantidadRestante = 0
            ORDER BY NumEntrega DESC
         END



            IF @SALDO_PENDIENTE13 = 0

            --SET @SALDO_PENDIENTE13 = @LaminaQty
            BEGIN

                INSERT INTO TBL_FS_Lamina_Surtida (Cod_Reg, Lamina,LaminaQty,CantidadInventario, CantidadRotorSurtida,NumEntrega, FechaEntrega, ActualizadaOracle, Usuario,  InventarioLamina_C, Estatus, EstatusSecuencia, NumSolicitud , NRotor,Stack, CantidadRotorRestante,InventarioRotor ) --, CantidadReSolicitada)
                VALUES(CAST(ltrim(rtrim(@Cod_reg)) as uniqueidentifier), @Lamina,@LaminaQty, @CantidadInventario, @CantidadRotorSurtida,@NumEntrega, GETDATE(), 0, @Usuario, null, 9, @EstatusSecuencia, @NUMSOLICITUD_ACTUAL, @NRotor, @Stack, @SALDO_RESTANTE2,@InventarioRotor ) --, @ReSolictada)


                UPDATE RF SET RF.Estatus = 9 FROM TBL_FS_Rotor_Lamina_Solicitada RF WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE Cod_Reg = CAST(ltrim(rtrim(@Cod_reg)) as uniqueidentifier) AND Estatus != 11 AND NumSolicitud = @NUMSOLICITUD_ACTUAL
                UPDATE TBL_FS_Lamina_Surtida set CantidadRotorRestante=@SALDO_RESTANTE3 FROM TBL_FS_Lamina_Surtida  WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE Cod_Reg = CAST(ltrim(rtrim(@Cod_reg)) as uniqueidentifier) 




            END
``
```

Comment: Por las dudas, el bloque tampoco se ejecuta si `@SALDO_PENDIENTE13`  es `NULL`, que sería el caso en que la consulta anterior no retorne filas.

Answer (score 1):

Buen día, en el lenguaje SQL no hay forma de declarar variables globales. Bajo esta lógica la variable @SALDO_PENDIENTE13 ya no cuenta con valor cuando la usas en el segundo bloque IF. Solamente existe y tiene un valor asignado en el primer bloque IF. Una alternativa que considero que podría ayudarte es el uso de IF anidados. Después de esta instrucción  ORDER BY NumEntrega DESC puedes escribir la palabra reservada ELSE y posteriormente escribir el segundo IF con las condiciones que deseas:

IF EXISTS (SELECT COD_REG FROM TBL_FS_Lamina_Surtida WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE Cod_Reg = CAST(ltrim(rtrim(@Cod_reg)) as uniqueidentifier) AND EstatusSecuencia != 4 AND NumSolicitud = @NUMSOLICITUD_ACTUAL)
        BEGIN
            SELECT TOP 1  @SALDO_PENDIENTE13 =  CantidadRestante --, @CantidadReSolicitada = ISNULL(CantidadReSolicitada,0)
            FROM TBL_FS_Lamina_Surtida WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE Cod_Reg = CAST(ltrim(rtrim(@Cod_reg)) as uniqueidentifier) 
            --AND EstatusSecuencia != 4
             --AND NumSolicitud = @NUMSOLICITUD_ACTUAL
             and CantidadRestante = 0
            ORDER BY NumEntrega DESC
-----> ELSE IF ..CONDICION
SENTENCIAS SQL
         END

te dejo una referencia respecto de lo que te comento de las variables globales en SQL

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22372359/how-to-declare-global-variable-in-sql-server
Espero que esto pueda ayudarte.